# Inequality of areas in elementary geometry

Tags: inequality, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area

During the IMC 2019 contest i ended up with the following question in elementary 2D Euclidean geometry:
Let $\mathrm{CDE}$ be any nondegenerate triangle inside a circle, consider the regions with areas labelled $S_1, S_2, S_3$ as on the picture. Prove that:
$$S_1 + S_2 + S_3 > S(CDE)$$
It must be known and i would be happy if anyone knows the elementary solution (it seems that i can d it by rough 5-pages calculations with cases).

It is also interesting to find the best possible constant $\lambda$ such that:
$$S_1 + S_2 + S_3 \geq \lambda \cdot S(CDE) $$
My guess is $\lambda = \frac{4\pi}{3\sqrt{3}} - 1\approx 1.418399$, that comes from equilateral inscribed triangle.

[image]

Comment: CDE "worst" case is when the points CDE are on the circle.

Comment: @Moti if you know the proof of that, then by a known fact that area is maximal for inscribed equilateral, the problem follows. But note that there are examples when difference between LHS and RHS arbitarly small.

Comment: What are LHS and RHS?

Comment: @Moti Left Hand Side, Right Hand Side, feel free to ask

Answer (score 1):

My proof is valid only when the circum-circle of CDE lies completely inside the original circle.

[image]

Locate H, the ortho-center of CDE.

EH extended will cut CDE at E’ and the circum-circle at E’’

By properties of the ortho-center, HE’ = E’E’’. Hence, [CHE’] = [CE’E’’]

The other parts of CDE can be off-set similarly. Result follows.

Comment: Cute construction, due to convexity we can require only points $E'$ and others to lie inside original circle. Unfortunately i don't know a short way to reduce to such case.

Comment: @RybinDmitry I think the key point is how the "non-degenerate triangle" is defined. I mean the original question could have been phrased differently.